# Adding vector arrows to tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphdrawing

I have code which outputs a number of parabolas

```
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) node[below left]{$x_2$}
   -- (0,0) --  (pX,0) node[below left]{$x_1$};
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   %\draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (2,0) arc(0:380:1);
   %\draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,-1) arc(-90:290:1);
   %\draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,0) arc(-90:380:1);
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 {\draw[-latex] (\X1) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 %
 \draw (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 % plane
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0.3] (-1,-4,0) -- (7,-4,0) --
  (7,4,0) -- (-1,4,0) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) -- (0,0) --  (pX,0);
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   %\draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (1,0) arc(0:380:0.25);
   %\draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,-0.25) arc(-90:290:0.25);
   %\draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,0.25) arc(-90:380:0.25);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[-latex] (4,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[below left]{$x_3$};
 \foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 {\draw[-latex] (\X2) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,-2) rectangle (4,3);
        \foreach \X in {-2,-1.6,...,2}
         {\draw (0,\X) parabola ++(5,1);}
       \end{scope} 
%       \draw[-stealth] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[below right]{$x_3$};
%       \draw[-stealth] (0,-0.5) node[above left]{$0$} -- (0,3)
%       node[right=2em,yshift=-1em]{$\theta(x_3)$};
%       \draw[-stealth] (4,-0.5) node[above left]{$L$} -- (4,3) node[below right]{$x_1$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which looks like [image: this.]

I am trying to replace the parabola curves by a series of lines 
like this
[image]
so as to make a series of layers with each layer having a random arrow direction. Can this be done in tikz? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds random arrows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) node[below left]{$x_2$}
   -- (0,0) --  (pX,0) node[below left]{$x_1$};
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 {\draw[-latex] (\X1) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 %
 \draw (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 % plane
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0.3] (-1,-4,0) -- (7,-4,0) --
  (7,4,0) -- (-1,4,0) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) -- (0,0) --  (pX,0);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[-latex] (4,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[below left]{$x_3$};
 \foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 {\draw[-latex] (\X2) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-2) rectangle (4,3);
      \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,...,2.75}
       {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myrnd}{rnd*360}
       \foreach \Y in {-1.75,-1.25,...,1.75}
        {
        \draw[-stealth] ({\X-0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y-0.2*sin(\myrnd)}) --
        ({\X+0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y+0.2*sin(\myrnd)});
        }
        \draw[densely dashed] (\X+0.25,-2) -- (\X+0.25,2);}
%       \foreach \X in {-2,-1.6,...,2}
%        {\draw (0,\X) parabola ++(5,1);}
   \end{scope} 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) node[below left]{$x_2$}
   -- (0,0) --  (pX,0) node[below left]{$x_1$};
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 {\draw[-latex] (\X1) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 %
 \draw (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 % plane
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0.3] (-1,-4,0) -- (7,-4,0) --
  (7,4,0) -- (-1,4,0) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) -- (0,0) --  (pX,0);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[-latex] (4,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[below left]{$x_3$};
 \foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 {\draw[-latex] (\X2) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 \foreach \Z in {0,0.5,...,2} 
  {\begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\Z]
   \begin{scope}
      \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,...,2.75}
       {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myrnd}{rnd*360}
       \foreach \Y in {-1.75,-1.25,...,1.75}
        {
        \draw[-stealth] ({\X-0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y-0.2*sin(\myrnd)}) --
        ({\X+0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y+0.2*sin(\myrnd)});
        }
        \draw[densely dashed] (\X+0.25,-2) -- (\X+0.25,2);}
%       \foreach \X in {-2,-1.6,...,2}
%        {\draw (0,\X) parabola ++(5,1);}
   \end{scope} 
  \end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect almost! How can I change this so that between each row of arrows there is a dotted line, and also, in each row all the arrows point in the same direction? I just want each row of arrows in the x3 direction to be at random directions.

Comment: @rodger_kicks Done.

Comment: This is perfect. I can't thank you enough. Is it easy to extend this into the x2 axis, to make the "layers" extend upwards? So that the dashed lines go upwards and the arrows repeat?

Comment: @rodger_kicks I added a loop over `\Z` :`\foreach \Z in {0,0.5,...,2} ` . You can change the values to move the arrows closer or further away from each other.